# Does twig support executing multiple statements inside a single {% %} block?

Tags: php, twig

Can I use construct like this in twig -

```
{% 
set a = 'first' 
set b = 'second' 
%}
```

instead of this -

```
{% set a = 'first' %}
{% set b = 'second' %}
```

Comment: I only know that this syntax is supported: `{% set a, b = 'first', 'second' %}` - more about this here: 
*[Twig Source Code](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/TokenParser/Set.php#L16-L26)*
and 
*[Twig Source Code #2](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/tree/master/test/Twig/Tests/Fixtures/tags/set)*

Answer (score 10):

You cannot execute several statements inside a single `{% ... %}` block, but the solution provided by CodeBrauer will do the trick. Anyway, keep in mind that the number of expressions on the left and on the right of the `=` sign must match.

This means that if the two (or three, etc.) variables share the same value, you must repeat that value. Example:

```
{# this will work as expected #}
{% set a, b, c = 'value', 'value', 'value' %}

{# this won't work #}
{% set a, b, c = 'value' %}
```